# Split and Append string at specific point

Tags: c#, winforms, api, split, append

i have use an web API

https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01&cloud_score=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY

And display the parameters above

Method input:
imagery?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01&cloud_score=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Expected Output:
Method name: imagery
Parameters: lon, lat, date, cloud_score, api_key
Values: 100.75, 1.5, 2014-02-01, True, api_key

Method input:
browse?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01

Expected Output:
Method name: browse
Parameters: lon, lat, date
Values: 100.75, 1.5, 2014-02-01

Method input:
?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01
Expected Output:

Error: malformed URL

Method input:
browse?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date

Expected Output:
Error: malformed URL

Method input:
browse?

Expected Output:
Error: malformed URL

Method input:
browse

Expected Output:
Method name: browse

i need to split the API from any word before the Question Mark

Here is my code so far

```
if (S == null || S=="")
{
    lbOutput.Text = "Please dont leave Fields Empty";

}
else
{
    if (S.Contains("?") || S.Contains("&"))
    {
        lbOutput.Text = "Output";
        string url = txtInput.Text;
        string querystring = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("?"));
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters =
            System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
        //lbOutput.Text = querystring;
        lbLonRes.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("lon");
        lbLatRes.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("lat");
        lbDateRes.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("date");
        lbCloudRes.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("cloud_score");
        lbAPIRes.Text = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring).Get("api_key");
    }
    if(S.Contains(" "))
    {
        lbOutput.Text = "Error: malformed URL";
        lbLonRes.Text = "";
        lbLatRes.Text = "";
        lbDateRes.Text = "";
        lbCloudRes.Text = "";
        lbAPIRes.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Segments` property of the `Uri` class to get the method since it will be the last segment.

You need a reference to `System.Net.HttpFormatting` to use this code, it will remove your dependence on `System.Web`

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&date=2014-02-01&cloud_score=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY";
            Uri theUri = new Uri(url);

            string method = theUri.Segments[theUri.Segments.Length - 1];

            Console.WriteLine("Method: {method}");

            var qa = theUri.ParseQueryString();

            foreach (string item in qa.AllKeys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"key: {item}, value: {qa[item]}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```